# How to load data on option box in php

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm having trouble loading the mysql data to the  option box using php. Here's my code:

```
<?php

  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","myuname","mypassword");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("school", $con);

 $idnum= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['idnum']);

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE IDNO='$idnum'");
?>

<?php while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) { ?>

<tr>
<td width="30" height="35"><font size="2">*I D Number:</td>
<td width="30"><input  name="idnum"  type="text" maxlength="5" value="<?php echo $row["IDNO"]; ?>" readonly="readonly"></td>
</tr>
```

My problem is loading it here:

```
<td><font size="2">Gender</td>
<td>
    <select name="gender" id="gender">
        <font size="2">
        <option value="<?php echo $line['IDNO']; ?> "><?php $line['GENDER'] ; ?></option>



    </select></td></td>
```

The table looks like this:

```
    IDNO | GENDER  
    123  |  M
    321  |  F
```

What am I supposed to do?To load the exact gender corresponding to the IDNO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** You are wrongly using the `$line` instead of `$row` for the options, hence not getting the result.

**Note 2:** From your query it looks, you are fetching just one record:

```
"SELECT * FROM student WHERE IDNO = '$idnum'"
```

And hence there is no need for the loop (I assume `IDNO` is primary key of the table). If however, you want to read all records of the table, your query should be something like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM student"
```

**How To Go About:**

Put the select box ***before*** the `while` loop:

```
<select name="gender" id="gender">
```

Then your `while` loop for options:

```
<?php while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['IDNO']; ?> "><?php $row['GENDER'] ; ?></option>
```

Close the `while` loop

```
<?php } ?>
```

And finally close the select box

```
</select>
```

So in all, your code should look something like this (excluding db stuff):

```
<select name="gender" id="gender">
  <?php while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row['IDNO']; ?> "><?php $row['GENDER'] ; ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood, your script loads two rows instead of one. Anyway, that's kind of weird because you have a very specific query (`SELECT * FROM student WHERE IDNO='$idnum'`)... so, why don't you change it to this?: `SELECT * FROM student WHERE IDNO='$idnum' LIMIT 1` so that you can now be sure it will load only one row.

bye!